# Need an easy if (empty) php code

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a bit of php to grab title tags on specific pages depending on what users homepage they are currently on. I am far from a pro php coder. What I came up with was this.

```
<title>
    <?php $member = get_user(); ?>
    <? wp_title(' | ', 'echo', 'right'); echo $member->member_title; ?>
</title>
```

This is currently working but I would like to have a fail-safe in case its left blank. Can anyone help me with a quick if (empty) for this?

Comment: What would you like to test for emptyness? `$member`? `$member_title`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $member = getUser();?>
<?php if(!empty($member->member_title)): ?>
    <title><? wp_title(' | ', 'echo', 'right'); echo $member->member_title; ?></title>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo (!empty($member->member_title)) ? $member->member_title : "member title was empty";
```